# Azure administrator login history

Tags: azure

Is there any option to see login history for company's Azure account, so we can see history which user (administrator) has logged in and when?

I see that `Active Directory Premium` has more reports, but I do not see anywhere login history.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately audit events for login and logout are not logged to `Audit logs` in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using AD premium edition(AD P1 (OR) AD P2) to view the log activities.
You can see the users log in activities as well as **Administrator login** activities and their IP and location on Sign-in-logs in theMonitoring menu of your Azure Active directory.